# iOS Setting the Root View Controller in IB or programmatically

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios

Are there any differences in performance by setting the Root View Controller in IB (by setting the `rootViewController` outlet for window to `f00` controller or by setting it in the Application Delegate by `self.window.rootViewController = self.f00;`

Which route would be the recommended route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no real performance issues:
in a simple application, either is fine,

in a more complex application, the root view might change,
and if you retain the last view being displayed (as user guidelines suggest)
you will want to wait until `appDid…` where you can make the decision to load
the standard root view or not,

in that situation, there would be a performance hit because you loaded a view/nib
that wasn't needed at application launch (but will likely be used later)